# cordova is not adding android platform

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-2.0.0

I am using windows 10. I have sucessfully installed android studio and java.
I am using latest android studio version 2.3.3. 
my cordova version is 7.0.1
nodejs version is 7.7.0
npm version is 4.1.2
I am using android **api level is 25**

when i am using `cordova platform add android` it shows the error

`Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT`

How to add the android platform .

Please solve my issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding the platform with lower versions of npm and node?

Comment: no. which version can use.

Comment: Can you try with npm 3.8.6 and node 5.12.0?

Comment: same problem again shows. My same configuration of npm, nodejs, cordova are used in another system. But not working for my system.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: can you please check this path and let me know what versions are in that folder. C:/Users/username/.cordova/lib/npm-cache/cordova-android

Comment: I have solved my problem by adding "C:\Windows\System32" in  enviromental variable path. And also i have installed git also. thanks u all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My enviromental variable path is missing "C:\Windows\System32". After adding the path. It have sucessfully running. And also i have installed git on my system.